# How to access Facebook Graph API in Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need to get friends of a user that logged in with Facebook at my Parse app, inside a cloud function. How can I achieve this? I've tried to install `facebook-node-sdk` (https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-node-sdk/), but even though I've copied all the dependencies into the same folder, it complains about being unable to load the package when I `require` it. I've also found this question: [How can I get the user first name from facebook in cloud code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22985553/how-can-i-get-the-user-first-name-from-facebook-in-cloud-code) but the answer there doesn't work (`FB` is not defined). I can do raw REST calls to Graph API with my access token using `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest` but managing endpoints, access token, parameters etc. quickly becomes messy. What is the preferred way of accessing Facebook Graph API from Parse Cloud Code?

Comment: Have you had any luck on this?

Comment: @Rambatino I've added my "solution" as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't use any libraries, so I've ended up using plain HTTP REST requests. For example, I was trying to get a user's name, gender, and user ID, I used this code by manually constructing the URL (where I had `token` access token variable of the user:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?fields=id,gender,name&access_token=' + token,
  success: function(httpResponse) {
     var responseData = httpResponse.data;
     ...
```

where `responseData` is now a JSON object with the returned data. It's not the best thing to do, but it works great for simple tasks.

Comment: I literally just used this method like an hour after i commented! Great stuff, works too! Although users will most likely be on v2.2 now :). 

Also, if anyone  is puzzled about authData even after include i still needed to fetch() the user to actually have a defined authData field :s

Comment: This might be a bit late but I've been trying to use this solution to no avail. The access token is not accepted and the graph API returns an error saying the access token is not active. Did you come across that issue?

Comment: :/ where do you get the access token in the first place.

Comment: @fatuhoku try `user.get('authData')['facebook']['access_token'];`